# Using aggregate with populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I am trying to use aggregate with populate. I need $group to variable of referenced ObjectId Schema. The structure is like:

```
var jobFilter = mongoose.Schema({    
        location    : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location' }, 
        field       : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Jobfield'} 
    })

var locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    city            : String,
    longitude       : Number,
    latitude        : Number
});
```

and i want to group by _field and city. I wrote this query but it did not work because of city. Is it possible to populate Location somehow in this query?

```
jobFilter.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    $match  : {
                        "jobFilter.field" : {$ne: null},
                        "jobFilter.location" : {$ne: null}}
                },
                {
                    $group  :
                    { _id: {
                        "field" : "$jobFilter.field" ,
                        "location" : "$jobFilter.location.city"
                    }, count: { $sum: 1}}},
                {
                    $sort   : { count : -1}
                }
            ]
        )
        .exec()
```

Comment: Then you either should be ["embedding"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) the data instead, or you will need a recent version of MongoDB of at least 3.2.x series so you can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). In reality, you probably should be "embedding", since it looks like you just created a design just like you would with a relational database when you should not have. MongoDB and relational databases work in completely different ways, so neither is a "drop in replacement" for the other.